Empty space when using [currentsection] in Beamer
I'm using the beamer class with the Frankfurt theme, but I'm having trouble with the alignment of the Table of Contents (TOC). It doesn't seem to align correctly.

Here's a snippet of my code:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\section[section1]{section1} \tableofcontents[currentsection]

% Table example
\begin{frame}{Sample Table}
Here is an example 
\end{frame}

% Graphic example
\begin{frame}{Sample Graphic}
Here is an example 
\end{frame}

\section[section2]{section2} \tableofcontents[currentsection]

% TikZ example
\begin{frame}{TikZ Example}
Here is an example 
\end{frame}

\section[section3]{section3} \tableofcontents[currentsection]

% Text example
\begin{frame}{Text Example}
Here is an example 
\end{frame}

\end{document}


You should add a frame environment around your \tableofcontents[currentsection]:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\newcommand\myToC
  {\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\section[section1]{section1} \myToC

% Table example
\begin{frame}{Sample Table}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

% Graphic example
\begin{frame}{Sample Graphic}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\section[section2]{section2} \myToC

% TikZ example
\begin{frame}{TikZ Example}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\section[section3]{section3} \myToC

% Text example
\begin{frame}{Text Example}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\end{document}

If you want to add a ToC on each section you can as well let beamer do it automatically by using \AtBeginSection:
\documentclass[italian,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\newcommand\myToC
  {\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}

\AtBeginSection{\myToC}

\begin{document}

\section[section1]{section1}

% Table example
\begin{frame}{Sample Table}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

% Graphic example
\begin{frame}{Sample Graphic}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\section[section2]{section2}

% TikZ example
\begin{frame}{TikZ Example}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\section[section3]{section3}

% Text example
\begin{frame}{Text Example}
Here is an example
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Result:


Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to prevent the TOC from being counted as a 'page'?

May be I found the answer myself:
\newcommand\myToC{   \begin{frame}[plain]     \frametitle{Table of Contents}     \tableofcontents[currentsection]   \end{frame}   \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1} } \AtBeginSection{\myToC}
